# Python crontab stops without error

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a Python/Django application running on an Ubuntu Server. The application updates the stock for a webshop.

I have made a job in crontab to update the stock every night.

```
# daily stock update, starts at 23:30
30 23 * * * ./Cronjobs/stockUpdate.sh
```

stockUpdate.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Projecten
source booksVenv/bin/activate
cd Books/books
cat stockUpdate.py | python manage.py shell
```

stockUpdate.py:

```
from core.models import Stock
Stock().getAllStock()
```

Running `Stock().getAllStock()` by hand works fine.
Example: I login on the server via ssh, start the virtual environment, start django shell and run the *getAllStock* method.

However, contrab just seems to stop while running `getAllStock` without an error. A log is placed in /var/mail/.

When I open the file with nano here is what I get.

```
# more than 500 pages of prints
Go to next page.
>>>
```

Here is what I think could be going wrong:
* I use too many print statements in my code, they mess up the job.
* The job starts at 23:30 but takes a few hours, it is stopped the next day (after a half hour).

Can someone please tell me why this is occurring and give me some details as to how to debug and fix the issue.

Comment: Which user is running the `stockUpdate.sh` are you sure the paths are correct? Why are you piping the `.py` script to shell? Django provides management commands to allow easily registering scripts in django framework. What tears down the shell? Does the shell continue to run indefinitely?  I've never tried piping python text to a shell so i'm not sure how it would act , but I could imagine it just hanging while the shell is open

Comment: Dunno if this will solve your problem, but regardless of that, worth checking out the `runscript` command provided by the django-extensions. It's good for running scripts like this. And it may solve your problem here if the issue is related to piping into the shell, which wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: My user is running the crontab jobs, sudo/admin rights are not used, file permissions are set so that I can run them.

Yes, the paths are correct and code starts running, it sends an email as soon as it starts.

I use piping because this was the only way I found to start the django shell and run code.

I should check if the shell is still running after the code stops. I do know that both Firefox and the virtual monitor are still running. The code should shut both when it is done. So it must be stopped somewhere during executing.

Comment: Are you setting the working directory and is `from core.models import Stock` on the path?

Comment: @dm03514, thanks for the tip. It was really easy to make a new management command. I'll let you guys know if this works.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the tips! The cronjob is working like it should.